# Book: Orphaned girl. fire, dancer/acrobat, grandfather, backwaters, wolves, werewolves?

Tags: story-identification, books, young-adult, werewolf

I'm looking for a book - probably Young Adult - English language.  Set in the USA.

It's about a girl who's orphaned after losing her mother (believe her father had left or died prior) in a fire.  The mother was a ballet-dancer and the girl is a dancer/acrobat/gymnast - dreaming of joining "Cirque de' Soleil".  The girl is about to start her final year of high-school and is 16 or 17.

After the funeral, her grandfather gets custody of her, and she has to take a plane from where she lives (somewhere sunny - perhaps California) to somewhere far north, very cold and very lightly populated.  On the plane, she overhears the passenger beside her mentioning staying at a leadership-seminar/resort to find his "inner animal/beast/wolf".

Her grandfather picks her up in an old truck, and they drive for hours into his cabin in the wilderness.   The leadership-resort is near by.  A boy drops by and tells her they go to the same school. and that he will drive her to and from school. At night, she hears wild animals.

The boy drives her to school - I don't think he's very popular.  Someone at school - I think a girl - died not long ago.  Everybody is curious about the new girl.

One time they drive back after school it's past dark.  The car gets some problems.  They get surrounded/attacked by wolves.

That's as far as I got...  Sadly I don't remember the title or author, so can anybody help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is almost certainly *Unleashed*, by Nancy Holder and Debbie Vegue, book one of the Wolf Springs Chronicle. I can't find any online text from the book, but a review that seems to nail it down:

> If you like stories about werewolves, small towns, and the anxiety of fitting in to a new place then these books will hold your interest. They are well written and interesting.  Katelyn McBride has lost her mother ( a Ballerina) in an earthquake, and her father (a prosecutor) who was murdered. Katelyn has to go to live with her grandfather,  who she hardly knows, in Wolf Springs.  It was Katelyn‘s dream to be a performer in Cirque du Soleil and she trained for years. but now that is out of the question. Her old life in Los Angeles  is over and her new life in Wolf Springs is about to begin. It’s a small town where everyone knows everyone else, and she is the new girl in town.

https://judysp.wordpress.com/2013/01/25/book-review-unleashed/

Comment: And for future reference, I found it by googling 'ya novel "cirque du soleil" wolves', it being the fourth result. Google is your friend!

Comment: Yes, that's the one - thanks!

Comment: Darn it... I wrote an answer, but lost my internet connection. Ah well. :P